# Why PHP script fails to capture icmp packets by raw socket?

Tags: php, sockets, icmp, raw

My PHP script uses raw socket to capture icmp packets, but actually it falis. the script is as follows:

```
<?php
$protocal = getprotobyname("icmp");
$socket   = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_RAW,$protocal) or die("Cannot create socket");

while(true){
   $read   = array($socket);  $write  = NULL;  $except = NULL;
   $select = socket_select($read, $write, $except, $timeout=1, 300*1000);

   if ($select === false){
       echo "socket_select error";
       continue;
   }
   elseif($select === 0){
       echo "SocketSelect time out";
       continue;
   }
   socket_recvfrom($socket, $recv, 65535, 0, $host, $port);
   print($recv);
   sleep(1);
}
?>
```

when I run the script on a host AAA with the ip of  192.168.1.72 on an Ethernet LAN ,and  I use "ping 192.168.1.72 -t" cmd on another host BBB , the ping cmd can get echo from host AAA, and  it is expected that the above running script on host AAA  can capture the icmp request packet from BBB and print some message, however  actually the script just print 'SocketSelect time out' repeatly .

can someone help to work out what is wrong with the php script ?

Comment: The network stack responds to ping packets itself, it doesn't pass them on to other processes.

Comment: If you want to capture packets that are being processed by other parts of the stack, you need to use BPF.

Comment: According to my knowledge, when icmp packets from host B comes to host A, the packets will firstly be got by host A's IP module of TCP/IP stack, and further IP module will deliver all of them to the registered modules, which include icpm moduel of tcp/ip stack as well as my PHP script, which has registerd icmp protocal to tcp/ip stack by socket_create function call with the third parameter(ICMP). so it is expected that the php script module can get the icpm packet, but it fails. what is wrong ? By the way, what is BPF ? @Barmar

Comment: BPF = [Berkeley Packet Filter](https://docs.kernel.org/bpf/index.html). It's the module used by tools like WireShark and `tcpdump`.